# Sort MongoDB documents by specific content then by timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

I'm using nodejs with official mongodb's package. I got many documents in mongodb containing "type" and "timestamp" field. I want to sort it by prioritizing "type" (only specific content) and then "timestamp".
As example I have following documents:

```
{ type: "book", timestamp: 1580825471 }
{ type: "house", timestamp: 1580825502 }
{ type: "water", timestamp: 1580825515 }
{ type: "book", timestamp: 1580825478 }
{ type: "smartphone", timestamp: 1580825522 }
{ type: "book", timestamp: 1580825424 }
```

My goal is to have sorted by that way to priority the type "book" first (and then sort it by timestamp)

```
{ type: "book", timestamp: 1580825478 }
{ type: "book", timestamp: 1580825471 }
{ type: "book", timestamp: 1580825424 }
{ type: "smartphone", timestamp: 1580825522 }
{ type: "water", timestamp: 1580825515 }
{ type: "house", timestamp: 1580825502 }
```

I was trying to use the db.collection.aggregate with following $sort value:

```
$sort: {
    type: "book",
    timestamp: -1
}
```

But that didn't worked out because the $sort field's value can only have the value of "**1**", "**-1**" or "**{ $meta: "textScore" }**".

Does anybody have an idea how to solve that issue?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

This solution by using

```
$sort: {
  type: 1,
  timestamp: -1
}
```

is **not a solution** since then all types are also sorted which I don't want it. I just want to have "book" as first result then after that, types can be randomized (but timestamp is still being sorted.). Reason for that is that I want to list history entries (that's why I'm using timestamp to sort it), but I want to show type "book" at first. Even if the document are older than other documents.
So yeah, for other types expect "book", I want it to be sorted by timestamp.

Comment: See your other message's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an extra field in a project stage that creates a sort priority, then use that to sort on.

For example:

```js
db.data.aggregate([
    { $addFields : { sortPriority: { $eq: [ "$type", "book" ] } } },
    { $sort: { sortPriority: -1, timestamp: -1} }
])
```

This will output the following:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e39892e0f18de54afe4d874"), "type" : "book", "timestamp" : 1580825478, "sortPriority" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e39892e0f18de54afe4d871"), "type" : "book", "timestamp" : 1580825471, "sortPriority" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e39892e0f18de54afe4d876"), "type" : "book", "timestamp" : 1580825424, "sortPriority" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e39892e0f18de54afe4d875"), "type" : "smartphone", "timestamp" : 1580825522, "sortPriority" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e39892e0f18de54afe4d873"), "type" : "water", "timestamp" : 1580825515, "sortPriority" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e39892e0f18de54afe4d872"), "type" : "house", "timestamp" : 1580825502, "sortPriority" : false }
```

If you want to ommit the extra field add `$unset` stage:

```js
db.data.aggregate([
    { $addFields : { sortPriority: { $eq: [ "$type", "book" ] } } },
    { $sort: { sortPriority: -1, timestamp: -1} },
    { $unset: "sortPriority" }
])
```

This will then output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e39892e0f18de54afe4d874"), "type" : "book", "timestamp" : 1580825478 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e39892e0f18de54afe4d871"), "type" : "book", "timestamp" : 1580825471 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e39892e0f18de54afe4d876"), "type" : "book", "timestamp" : 1580825424 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e39892e0f18de54afe4d875"), "type" : "smartphone", "timestamp" : 1580825522 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e39892e0f18de54afe4d873"), "type" : "water", "timestamp" : 1580825515 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e39892e0f18de54afe4d872"), "type" : "house", "timestamp" : 1580825502 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the best solution!! =)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a sorting key by your own:

```
db.col.aggregate([
   {
      $addFields: {
         sortBy: {
            $cond: {
               if: { $eq: ["$type", "book"] }, then: 0, else: 1
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $sort: { sortBy: 1, timestamp: 1 } },
   { $unset: "sortBy" }
])
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e398952227b6d209de231bb"), "type" : "book", "timestamp" : 1580825424, "sortPriority" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e398952227b6d209de231b6"), "type" : "book", "timestamp" : 1580825471, "sortPriority" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e398952227b6d209de231b9"), "type" : "book", "timestamp" : 1580825478, "sortPriority" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e398952227b6d209de231b7"), "type" : "house", "timestamp" : 1580825502, "sortPriority" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e398952227b6d209de231b8"), "type" : "water", "timestamp" : 1580825515, "sortPriority" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e398952227b6d209de231ba"), "type" : "smartphone", "timestamp" : 1580825522, "sortPriority" : false }
```

Comment: change "timestamp: 1" to "timestamp: -1" then it should be a correct solution too! Thank you so much!